# Google Apps Script: Get an array of dates between two dates

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm building a time sheet spreadsheet. I'd like to include a function that allows the user to enter a period of Leave, by entering the start date and end date, which then automatically marks out the dates in between. I have the following, which enters the value against the relevant Start and End date, but not the dates in between. Is there away to build an array of the dates that I can then loop though?

```
function updateLeave() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Front Page");
 var startDate = ss.getRange("C15").getValue();
 var endDate = ss.getRange("C16").getValue();
 var type = ss.getRange("C17").getValue(); 
 var creditTime = ss.getRange("C18").getValue();

 var allSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheets = allSheets.getSheets();
 sheets.forEach (function (sheet) {

 var columnB = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 70, 1); 
 var bValues = columnB.getValues(); 
 var today = startDate; 
 for (var i = 0; i < bValues.length; i++) { 
 var fDate = new Date(bValues[i][0]);
 if (fDate.getDate() == today.getDate() && 
    fDate.getMonth() == today.getMonth() && 
    fDate.getFullYear() == today.getFullYear()) { 
    sheet.getRange(i + 2, 10, 1, 1).setValue(type);
    sheet.getRange(i + 2, 9, 1, 1).setValue(creditTime);  
}
}
})

sheets.forEach (function (sheet) {

var columnB = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 70, 1); 
var bValues = columnB.getValues(); 
var today = endDate; 
for (var i = 0; i < bValues.length; i++) { 
var fDate = new Date(bValues[i][0]);
if (fDate.getDate() == today.getDate() && 
    fDate.getMonth() == today.getMonth() && 
    fDate.getFullYear() == today.getFullYear()) { 
    sheet.getRange(i + 2, 10, 1, 1).setValue(type);
    sheet.getRange(i + 2, 9, 1, 1).setValue(creditTime);  
}
}

})
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about something like this:

```
var DAY_MILLIS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

function main() {
  var a = new Date('2016/01/01');
  var b = new Date('2016/01/03');
  var dates = createDateSpan(a, b);
}

function createDateSpan(startDate, endDate) {
  if (startDate.getTime() > endDate.getTime()) {
    throw Error('Start is later than end');
  }

  var dates = [];

  var curDate = new Date(startDate.getTime());
  while (!dateCompare(curDate, endDate)) {
    dates.push(curDate);
    curDate = new Date(curDate.getTime() + DAY_MILLIS);
  }
  dates.push(endDate);
  return dates;
}

function dateCompare(a, b) {
  return a.getFullYear() === b.getFullYear() &&
    a.getMonth() === b.getMonth() &&
    a.getDate() === b.getDate();
}
```

The `main` function shows an example of use

Comment: Ok, great. That seems to work, but I can't figure out how to get it into my script to loop through each date an enter it into the relevant cell.

Comment: What are you then trying to do with the list of dates? Where would you like them placed on the Sheet?

Comment: The project is a timesheet. So each month has it's own sheet. If a user has a week off and needs to enter that time what they currently do is enter the Start Date and End Date and the script goes and looks for those dates and inserts a record against them.

What I need it to do is also enter the record against each date in between the Start and End Date.

Comment: Why is  ```a.getDate() === b.getDate()``` not enough for the comparison.